# C++ how convert wide string to base64?

Tags: c++, base64, widestring

What is the best way to convert wide string to base64?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Octet (8 bit symbols) -> Base64 (6 bit symbols) conversion works on bytes, not characters, so it works the same way independent of your string encoding.

---

To be clear: Base64 is not a character encoding.  Sender and receiver need to agree on the character encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, UCS-2, etc) as well as the transport method (Base64, gzip, etc).

Comment: To clarify, since a `wchar_t` is not an octet, you have to convert wide strings to arrays of octets before base64 encoding.

Comment: To clarify further, you need to decide whether to convert your wide string to an intermediate form like UTF-8 before encoding to Base64, or to just skip that, typecast the `wchar_t*` to `const char*` and encode to Base64.

Comment: @Dietrich, @Mike: A well-designed conversion API would be taking a `void*`.  The size of the chunks the API processes at a time is completely an implementation detail, and it might very well use 16- or 32-bit words internally.  `void*` is the right type for binary data (see also `fread`, `memcpy`).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: But a `wchar_t` is not portable, so if you reverse the encoding on a different platform, you will get a mangled string.  Some platforms have 16-bit, others have 32-bit `wchar_t`.  Some are big or little endian.  Since `wchar_t` is not byte oriented, it should not be base64 encoded, whether or not the API generates a type error.

Comment: @Dietrich: That's true, but no one but you is talking about `wchar_t`.  Regardless, Base64 preserves the encoding whatever it is.  Your comments do apply to Kirill's answer though.  But I've added to my answer to clarify this.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: The question title is "wide string", or does that mean something else besides a string of `wchar_t`...?

Comment: @Dietrich: It could mean that, or `char16_t`, and `char32_t`, or any other string with characters outside the ASCII range.  If we're being generous, even UTF-8 could qualify.

Comment: @Ben: "Wide string" is defined as a sequence of wide characters in the relevant standard.  "Wide character" is defined as `wchar_t`.  The terms "multibyte character" or "multibyte string" are used when speaking of `char16_t` and `char32_t`, strings of which may be *initialized with* wide string literals.  I have never heard the term "wide string" outside the C/C++ community, so I use the definition from the C/C++ standards.

Answer (score 1):

To encode some data to base64 you can use [Base64](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classBase64.html) class from the Xerces library. It could look like the following:

```
std::wstring input_string = SOME; // some wide string
// keep it in contiguous memory (the following string is not needed in C++0x)
std::vector<wchar_t> raw_str( input_string.begin(), input_string.end() );

XMLSize_t len;
XMLByte* data_encoded = xercesc::Base64::encode( reinterpret_cast<const XMLByte*>(&raw_str[0]), raw_str.size()*sizeof(wchar_t), &len );
XMLCh* text_encoded = xercesc::XMLString::transcode( reinterpret_cast<char*>(data_encoded) );

// here's text_encoded is encoded text
// do some with text_encoded

XMLString::release( &text_encoded );
XMLString::release( reinterpret_cast<char**>(&data_encoded) );
```

Comment: This is a solution where no intermediate form such as UTF-8 is used.

Comment: Very useful code showing how to release the memory allocated by xercesc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual C++ with MFC, there is already a library to do this. Check out `Base64Encode` and `Base64Decode`.